# Reading part of a file, in powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to read part of a file, starting from one string to ending another string. Is there a way to do this?
Eg: 1.txt contains

```
/string1
 phone 
 lapi
 desk

/string2
 ipod
 socket
```

Like that the file will be and here the string1 is constant and string2 may vary. But "/" will be constant at other end. Please suggest me, tried with get-content but it is a bit lengthy code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of what you tried and describe both the results you expected and the results you actually got.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use Get-Content it's not so lengthy.
If you wish to split between charachter / then just execute this:

```
    $contents = Get-Content -Path .\YourFile.txt -Delimiter '/'
```

then the contents would be an array where first and second part would be the text which you want. Of course end has / character so you may want to trim

```
    $text = $contents[0] + $contents[1].Trim('/');
```

Comment: Sorry for not elaborating, But the strings are not limited to two. There are many such formats in that i need to get from required string(stingN) to the delimiter(/).

Comment: What is your goal? If you need process those string just use for cycle from 1 to $contents.Length and trim each $content while processing.